# The VSCode problemMatcher $gcc seems to be gone

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

My tasks are configured to use the `$gcc` problemMatcher. This used to work fine, but now vscode complains:

```
{
    "resource": "/home/src/example/.vscode/tasks.json",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "1",
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Value is not accepted. Valid values: \"$msCompile\", \"$lessCompile\", \"$gulp-tsc\", \"$jshint\", \"$jshint-stylish\", \"$eslint-compact\", \"$eslint-stylish\", \"$go\", \"$lessc\", \"$node-sass\", \"$tsc\", \"$tsc-watch\".",
    "startLineNumber": 11,
    "startColumn": 31,
    "endLineNumber": 11,
    "endColumn": 37
}
```

As you can see `$gcc` is not in the list of valid values. How come ?

This is my VSCode version:

```
Version: 1.38.1
Commit: b37e54c98e1a74ba89e03073e5a3761284e3ffb0
Date: 2019-09-11T13:30:08.229Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.0.0-29-generic
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Have you tried the answer below ? At the time of writing it did the trick.

Comment: Doesn't that answer say the opposite, that when they installed that extension they no longer had the $gcc option? So are you saying you disabled this extension and the problemMatcher worked again?

Comment: You can also read it as "I noticed the same error [. But] when I enabled ms-code.cpptools, it disappeared. " Why not try it out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed the same error,but when I enabled `ms-code.cpptools` it disappeared.

[image: Screenshot of addon]